# Discord Bot checking if key from json present in message

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json

with open(r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\rijalbot\rijaldata\narrators.json") as f:
    narrators = json.load(f)



class cmds(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client


    @commands.command()
    async def rijal(self, ctx, message):
      if narrators.keys() in ctx.message:
          val = narrators.get(ctx.message)
          if val == "weak":
              await ctx.send("True")
```

narrators.json

```
{"a": "weak"}
```

I want my discord bot to check if my message contains a key from a json, but everytime I run it, and execute the [!rijal a] command, it does nothing, it should send "True"

Answer (score 1):

`narrators.keys()` is a view of all keys in the dictionary. The `message` is a string, so `narrators.keys()` will never be in `message`.

`narrators.get(message)` also won't work if the message isn't exactly the same. You're using `in`, so you're just looking for substrings. For example: `"a"` is *in* `"another"`, but `{"a": "weak"}.get("another")` won't find a match, because `"another"` isn't inside of the dictionary.

If you want substrings, loop over the keys instead. To get the value, get it from the dict using the corresponding `key` instead of the `message`, as that won't work (as described above). An alternative is to loop over both the keys & values at the same time using `items`.

If you want full matches, `get()` will return `None` if nothing was found.

*PS consider using an actual database instead of a JSON file*